# Table inheritance: Enforcing unique constraints across partitions?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, constraints, database-partitioning

I have a table that I would like to partition, but I don't know how to deal with the uniqueness constraints.

Is it possible to create a unique constraint across multiple child tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. The best you can do is to create a trigger that does the verification manually.

Comment: While this is true (+1), it is worth to note that if the unique field is the one the table is partitioned along then a unique constraint defined on child tables will make the values unique across th whole table.  On the other hand, since redirecting `INSERT`s into child tables already requires a trigger, that very trigger can check uniqueness as well.

Comment: It is possible to create unique constraint across partitions since postgresql 11:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/11.0/
"Support indexes on partitioned tables (Álvaro Herrera, Amit Langote)"